# How many occurences of the empty string in a string?

Tags: formal-languages

Given two strings s and t, we can ask how many occurences of s are in t. For example, "bb" occurs in "bbbb" 3 times. But how many occurences of the empty string are in a string? How would we define that?

Comment: How do you count the three occurrences of $bb$ in $bbbb$? That is, how do you distinguish one occurrence from another? The three occurrences all look exactly the same: $bb$; therefore you must look at something about the surrounding parts of the string. Figure out what that thing is, and you may have something like Henning Makholm's answer.

Comment: As stated, there's no reason to suppose there's any such thing as "the number of times the empty string appears".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My immediate approach would be to reformulate the question to

> How many *different* pairs of strings $(x,y)$ are there such that $t=xsy$?

If $s$ is the empty string, the answer to this is $|t|+1$.